# Get Text value from Select and put value in a label

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs2

Hi I'm new to Laravel and Vue so please bear with me.

I now have the following

```
                    <option v-for="packhouse in packhouses"
                            value="@{{packhouse.id}}">

                            @{{packhouse.PlantName}}

                    </option>

                </select>

                <label>@{{ selectLabel }}</label>
```

and

```
                    <script>
var packhouses = {!!  json_encode($plants) !!};
```

new Vue({
            el: '#root',
            data:   {  key: '',
                            select: '',
                        message: 'Hello World'
                    },
            methods:{

```
                    onChange(event)
                                {
                                    console.log(event.target.value);
                                    VownerTitle = '9999';

                                }
                },

        computed: {

                    selectLabel() {

                        if (!this.selected) return 'Make a selection';

                            return this.packhouses.find(opt => opt.id == this.selected).PlantName;

                        }

                    },
    });
```

The 'Make a selection' doesn't go away after selecting something. When I change

value="@{{packhouse.id}}">

to

v-bind:value="@{{packhouse.id}}">

The page loads/flashes for a second then disappears

Comment: Can you show your Vue instance data?

Comment: I don't understand this line `I want the PlantName value in a PlantName`

Comment: Do you have something like `data() {return { packhouse: { id: null}}};'` at your Vue component?

Comment: You haven't shown us ***where exactly*** you are using the `v-model` directive, and ***where exactly*** you tried using `v-bind:value...`. Also, you've mentioned you are trying to update a label, but I don't see a `<label>` anywhere in the code you've shown us. We can't help you without seeing more of your code.